# WP Технические страницы мультиязычного сайта. Нужно ли делать разные версии?

Tags: wordpress, seo, multilanguage

Есть некий мультиязычный сайт `https://example.net/` У него есть информационные страницы по типу `/about-us/` `/call-back/` `/privacy-policy/` и тд. трафик эти страницы не генерируют, но и в robots.txt их лучше от ботов не скрывать.

В связи с чем у меня вопрос, есть ли смысл делать переводы контекста этих страниц по типу `/about-us/it/` `/call-back/it/` `/privacy-policy/it/` например для Итальянской версии сайта, создавая новые страницы, или же лучше перевести контент, Title и meta description тексты в словарях темы сайта? *не могу в документациях найти лучшее решение, а встречал и тот и другой вариант.

Comment: Надо делать мультиязычность не на коленке, а через нормальные плагины типа WPML или Polylang, и тогда всё будет правильно в плане SEO. Там будут созданы страницы `/it/about-us` и т.д.

Comment: Кроме "генерации" траффика из ПС нужно думать о людях. Если конечно это сайт для людей. Тогда такие вопросы не возникают.

Comment: Плагин используется, вопрос не о том. Это не про главную и не про посты. Можно сделать одну страницу  `/about-us/`  а можно лупить 100500 под разные версии мультиязычности на которых контент будет отличаться.  Если бы у вас была задача сделать страницу портфолио Ваших навыков на WordPress (да одну страницу), вы ставили б плагин и плодили '/me/'  '/me/de/' '/me/tr/' или же сделали бы одну ? а потом просто создали папку /language/ в которую б положили словари `.po .mo` ?  Это больше не про разработку а про продвижение...